# What races would the drow be using as slaves?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, golarion, adventure-path, darklands, drow

I'm running the Second Darkness Adventure Path under Pathfinder rules. I have had to make many changes in the 3rd book to have a more balanced game, partly because my party size is 8 people.

I own the Drow of the Underdark book from 3.5 and have started using it as a reference for different aspects. Both Pathfinder and 3.5 agree that Drow are slavers, and that they willing use slaves for combat as expendable troops. But for the Golarion setting I'm having a real hard time coming up with what races their slaves should be. So far the book has had some trog's working for them, and the rest are slaves.

What races should I be using? I know they're willing to enslave pretty much anyone but I'm not really coming up with what would be good slaves (and their stats) when they're being used for a city combat. The city is an old city on the surface that belonged to the elves before the drow existed, something happened and some went underground and became the drow. The city remained abandoned for a very long time and now the drow are trying to take over the surface and this is their first staging area.

Why are people down-voting this question? What is wrong with it? Please leave in the comments.

Comment: Don't answer in comments. Fering, the downvotes were probably from the previous lack of clarity (what game world?) and grammar/formatting, post the edit I gave it I would think that would nip most of the downvoting in the bud.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no "generic" answer, like everything else about D&D it varies by game world.

In Paizo's Golarion campaign setting, then your key references are the Second Darkness Adventure Path and the [Into the Darklands](http://paizo.com/products/btpy85ej/discuss?Pathfinder-Chronicles-Into-the-Darklands) campaign setting book. Generally they keep as slaves "whoever they can get their hands on that is useful and tractable."  This includes everything from troglodytes to other drow to surface folk to driders to dark creepers to "balor-possessed greater water elementals" (all these are listed as slaves in that drow city you're talking about).

> To drow mores, anything and anyone who is not a
>   drow is a candidate for slavery. Their word for servitor is
>   anquestra, while their word for outlander is jenanquestrok,
>   which means “not yet a slave.” Sentients that are spoils
>   of war are always considered slaves, especially if the
>   purpose of the war is to gather more servitors. Similarly,
>   non-drow trespassers can be declared anquestra, and
>   this can happen even to non-drow offered protection
>   from a noble house, should another noble house want
>   to enslave them.

In the drow culture part of The Armageddon Echo it says "drow don't enslave other drow, but some do become servants" and then in Endless Night it refers to drow slaves about a zillion times, who seem to meet the standard end of slaves, so YMMV.

If you want a list of other darklands races that might be good candidates, consider checking out the [Pathfinder Wiki's Darklands](http://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Darklands) and subsidiary entries, or the list of [creatures whose habitat is underground from the d20PFSRD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/-bestiary-by-terrain/-bestiary-terrain-underground).

Comment: I had not heard of the Darklands book so I will look for it. I havent read the paths after the book Im working on, and yes Ive encountered differing details which makes it hard. But with the races you listed I have a starting point, thank you

Comment: Keeping [troglodytes](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/humanoids/troglodyte) as slaves seems like more [trouble](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Stench-Ex-) than it's worth. Does the text mention for what the drow use the enslaved troglodytes?

Comment: Menial tasks and stuff; they're suitable once made docile.   Trogs also come and go in their cities as poor travelers (there's a flophouse they stay in in the city). Oh and they fleshwarp them into a new monster in the AP too.

Comment: Maybe a look at common fleshwarps http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/fleshwarped-cr-1#TOC-Common-Fleshwarps might be a good idea too. It lists drow, troglodytes, gnomes, humans, goblins, vegepygmies, elves, halflings, orcs and ogres.